# Change data requirements of an input field based on the value of a select field in a web form

Tags: php

I am working on a web form that includes a select drop down with two options: "Cedula" (in English, "Identification") and "Pasaporte" (in English, "Passport").

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nm6W.png) is an image of my web form so far.

Please help me achieve the following goal: when the user selects "Cedula", they are limited to 10 digits, but when they select "Pasaporte, they are not limited to 10 digits.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id']) {
    $cliente = $clienteNegocio->recuperar($_GET['id']);
    $txtAction = 'Editar';          
}else{
    $cliente = new cliente();
    $txtAction = 'Agregar';
}

?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo $txtAction; ?> Cliente</h1>
  </div>
    <form role="form" method="post" id="principal">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>" >
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNombre();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $cliente->getApellido();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tipoDoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tipoDoc" name="tipoDoc">
                <option value="Cedula"  <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Cedula') {echo "selected";} ?>  >Cedula</option>
                <option value="Pasaporte" <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Pasaporte') {echo "selected";} ?> >Pasaporte</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nroDoc">Numero de Documento</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" maxlength=10 oninput="if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
             name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Documento" value="<?php echo $cliente ->getNroDoc();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go.

I have written a javascript function to check the length with you select Pasaporte/Cedula.

Secondly, in `<input type = "number"/>` you cannot set maxLength. Hence you have to set `<input type = "text" />`. Also, an `onKeyPress` event to verify the input as number

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id']) {
    $cliente = $clienteNegocio->recuperar($_GET['id']);
    $txtAction = 'Editar';          
}else{
    $cliente = new cliente();
    $txtAction = 'Agregar';
}

?>

<script>
function setMaxLength(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("tipoDoc")
    var selIndex = inputVal.options[inputVal.selectedIndex].value
    var inputNum = document.getElementById("nroDoc");


    if( selIndex === "Cedula"){

        inputNum.maxLength = 10
        selIndex.substr(0, 9);
        inputNum.value = inputNum.value.substr(0, 9);

    } else{

        // Set your own limit here
        // if selIndex === "Pasaporte"
        inputNum.maxLength = 20
    }
}
</script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo $txtAction; ?> Cliente</h1>
  </div>
    <form role="form" method="post" id="principal">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>" >
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNombre();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $cliente->getApellido();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tipoDoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tipoDoc" name="tipoDoc" onChange="setMaxLength()">
                <option value="Cedula"  <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Cedula') {echo "selected";} ?>  >Cedula</option>
                <option value="Pasaporte" <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Pasaporte') {echo "selected";} ?> >Pasaporte</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nroDoc">Numero de Documento</label>
            <!-- 
                Here onKeyPress method is used to check if the input is a number
                in <input type = "number"/> you cannot set maxLength
                hence you have to set <input type = "text" />
            -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" maxlength=10 onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
             name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Documento" value="<?php echo $cliente ->getNroDoc();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```